# Is there anyway to pass a type or subtype into and out of a function

Tags: vhdl

Food for thought.

I'm working with a lot of data information which is passed in and out of records, vectors and ram. 
For this i like to make my code very simple because it can get quite complex fast.

I was working the other day with some information I'm reading out of a memory block.

The upper part of this data contains information defined in a package file. 
I've tried to make an example below.

I have a 8 bit information + 64 bits of data IE a vector 71 downto 0;
The information byte is in turn divided into nibbles and I've created two constant vectors with defined ranges..

```
constant nibble_one : std_logic_vector(7 downto 4) := X"F";
constant nibble_two : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := X"2";
```

and the vector for the output of the memory

```
signal data_out : std_logic_vector(71 downto 0);
```

now I need to stop reading from the memory when

```
data_out(71 downto 68) = nibble_one;
```

and it can of course be done in multiple ways, like the above which is fine. But now comes the fun part.  I thought that it must be possible to do the following by overloading the "+" operator.

```
data_out(nibble_one'range + 64) = nibble_one;
```

Which would look nice. however I hit a snag. How do I pass the 'range value into a function and out again for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can elevate types to first class values, manipulable at runtime, without turning VHDL into a dynamically typed language. Which isn't going to happen.

Which means there is no way to write a function such as '+' returning a type; only a value (e.g. an integer, array, or record). Returning a value pair in an array or record would work, but be ugly to use.

So you have to create the types up front. Which is in keeping with the static typing philosophy : explicit declarations to allow the compiler to clean as much as it can.

If this is the only use of nibble_one there is nothing wrong with

```
constant nibble_one : std_logic_vector(71 downto 68) := X"F";
```

then your expression simplifies to

```
    data_out(nibble_one'range) = nibble_one;
```

Otherwise you need something uglier, such as the explicit solution:

```
    data_out((nibble_one'left + 64) downto (nibble_one'right + 64))
```

However you can at least confine the ugliness to one place:

```
constant MS_Nibble : std_logic_vector(nibble_one'left + 64) 
                              downto (nibble_one'right + 64) := nibble_one;

    data_out(MS_Nibble'range) = nibble_one;
```

Or a comparison function :

```
function equal (word : std_logic_vector; nibble : std_logic_vector; 
         offset : natural) return boolean is
begin
   assert nibble'left + offset <= word'left and
          nibble'right + offset >= word'right
   report "Compare_range error" severity failure;
   return word(nibble'left + offset downto word(nibble'right + offset) = nibble;
end equal;
```

then in your loop,

```
    exit when equal(data_out, nibble_one, offset => 64);
```

Comment: I do not know how subtypes work as such. Though you have the 'left and 'right which returns a integer and this you can pass to a function just fine. I though maybe the 'range would return a record which also contained the above 'left and 'right. Though i like your solution with the constant MS_Nibble :). thank you for your answer

Comment: No, subtypes are not records and don't automatically translate into records. (Though that might be worth suggesting to the P.1076 language committee). Using 'left and 'right and passing 2 parameters may be the simplest approach.

Comment: Addtion to above. I forgot that you can make a subtype of only a range IE `subtype nibble_one_range_offest is natural range nibble_one'LEFT + 64 downto nibble_one'RIGHT + 64;` and then use this as the index `data_out(nibble_one_range_offest) = nibble_one;` because this is possible i thought it also would have been possible to pass subtypes into and out of functions :)

Comment: Well it might work if it was possible to create dynamic subtypes as it is possible to create dynamic types. If you could create a sybtype the following way. `subtype param is natural range <>` then you could use this in your function like this `function "+" (L : param, R : integer) return param;` but i do not know the workings in the code behind this so i dont know if this would ever be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Other methods are better, but the closest thing I could think of to what you tried is something like:

```
function offset_range(s : std_logic_vector; offset : natural) return std_logic_vector is
  variable so : std_logic_vector(s'high + offset downto s'low + offset);
begin
  return so;
end function offset_range

...

data_out(offset_range(nibble_one, 64)'range) = nibble_one
```

It works, but it's not exactly pretty. It would be much more conventional to write the function so that it takes data_out as an argument and returns just the desired slice, of course.

(edit): I should clarify that this solution is intended as more of an experiment than a solution I would actually suggest employing.

Answer (score 1):

An impure function returning part of `data_out` provides kind of the format, but required a specific function for each signal to extract from:

```
  constant nibble_one : std_logic_vector(7 downto 4) := X"F";
  constant nibble_two : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := X"2";

  signal data_out : std_logic_vector(71 downto 0);

  impure function data_out_part(nibble : std_logic_vector; offset : integer) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
    return data_out(nibble'left + offset downto nibble'right + offset);
  end function;

  signal data_out_part_sig : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- For example below

begin

  data_out_part_sig <= data_out_part(nibble_one, 64);  -- Example of use
```

Comment: Yeah this is one way to do it and it's clean as it can be. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Funny that you answer my first question on this forum :). Regards Anders

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use (or overload) the plus operator the way you want to. However, a simple solution would be:

```
data_out((nibble_one'left + 64) downto (nibble_one'right + 64)) = nibble_one;
```

(Assuming you are using `downto`ranges only.)